# SQL Server stored procedure query multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am querying a SQL Server database using a stored procedure.

My database tables include:

- Customers
- SalesOrders - Linked to the customers with an id
- SalesOrderLines - Linked to the SalesOrders with an id
- SalesOrderReleases - Linked to the SalesOrderLines with an id, stores the quantity on the order line that has been released and ready to manufacture, the SalesOrderLine quantity can be all on one release or split up on multiple
- FinishedGoods - linked to the SalesOrderLines with an id, stores the quantity of the SalesOrderLine where manufacturing is complete, the SalesOrderLine quantity can be all on one FinishedGood entry or split up on multiple

I need to retrieve all the customers that have SalesOrderLines with SalesOrderReleases and FinishedGoods where the total quantity finished is less than the total quantity released

I have tried this SQL code but Customers appear repeatedly in the results

```
SELECT 
    Customer.ID, Customer.Name 
FROM 
    Customer
INNER JOIN 
    SalesOrder ON Customer.ID = SalesOrder.CustomerID
INNER JOIN 
    SalesOrderLine ON SalesOrder.ID = SalesOrderLine.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN 
    SalesOrderRelease ON SalesOrderLine.ID = SalesOrderRelease.SalesOrderLineID
INNER JOIN 
    FinishedGood ON SalesOrderLine.ID = FinishedGood.SalesOrderLineID AND FinishedGood.Quantity < SalesOrderRelease.Quantity
```

I am looking for a SQL code snippet that will query multiple tables the way I have described.

Comment: Please post DDL, sample data, and expected - "it doesn't work correctly" doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: Order is a SQL reserved word for the ORDER clause of the SELECT statement. You should never use such an SQL identifier. SORelease is a name (or alias) you use in a predicate, that does not figures in the query text as an alias or a table/view name...

Comment: No need to bracket joins in SQL Server. Do you need to sum any of the tables?

Comment: Why do you have all of those parenthesis in your `FROM`? What are they trying to achieve? `INNER JOIN Order` isn't going to work, as the error (you haven't told us) tells you "Incorrect syntax near the ***keyword*** 'Order'." `ORDER` is a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and should not be used for object names. If you "have" to use it, then you must delimit identify your object.

Comment: The basic query would be in the form of `select ... from dbo.Customer as cust where exists (select ... from dbo.Order as ord inner join ... where ord.CustomerID = cust.CustomerID) order by ...;` I leave it to you to fill in the subquery correctly and to also find the best practices that you need to develop.

Comment: In response to SQLpro and Larnu, the table names I have used in this sample code are just sample table names, the table names on my end are not causing any errors, I have updated the table names in my sample code to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to [Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11392290/sergey) for his answer, I was able to use the sample code he provided with several slight modifications:

```
SELECT Customer.ID, Customer.Name FROM Customer
INNER JOIN SalesOrder ON Customer.ID = SalesOrder.CustomerID
INNER JOIN SalesOrderLine ON SalesOrder.ID = SalesOrderLine.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN
(SELECT SalesOrderID, SalesOrderLineID, SUM (Quantity) AS SRQuantity FROM 
    SalesOrderRelease GROUP BY SalesOrderID, SalesOrderLineID) AS SRQ
    ON SRQ.SalesOrderLineID = SalesOrderLine.SalesOrderID
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT SalesOrderLineID,  SUM (Quantity) AS  FGQuantity FROM 
    FinishedGood GROUP BY SalesOrderLineID) AS FGQ
        ON  SRQ.SalesOrderLineID = FGQ.SalesOrderLineID
    WHERE ISNULL(FGQ.FgQuantity, 0) < SRQ.SRQuantity
```

- The last join needed to be a Left Join
- When comparing the FgQuantity and the SRQuantity in the last line, I needed to have it check for NULL values

With these modifications everythings works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
SELECT Customer.ID, Customer.Name FROM Customer
    INNER JOIN SalesOrder ON Customer.ID = Order.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN SalesOrderLine ON Order.ID = OrderLine.OrderID
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT OrderID, OrderLineID, SUM (Quantity) AS SRQuantity FROM 
      SalesOrderRelease GROUP BY OrderID, OrderLineID) AS SRQ
        ON SRQ.OrderID = SalesOrderLine.OrderID

 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT OrderLineID,  SUM (Quantity) AS  FGQuantity FROM 
       FinishedGoods GROUP BY OrderLineID) AS FGQ
         ON  SRQ.OrderLineID = FGQ.OrderLineID
   WHERE FGQ.FgQuantity < SRQ.SRQuantity
```

Comment: I get an error, "The multi-part identifier "SalesOrderLineID.OrderID" could not be bound", on SalesOrderLineID.OrderID in your sample code, what is this referencing?

Comment: It is just typo. Use SalesOrderLine